# Get geo location with MDM

Tags: ios, push-notification, mdm

I just wanted to send a silent push notification to the device and in response I wanted to call `API` to sent the user geo location with the help of `MDM server`.

As I studied `MDM` can do `silent push notification` but need to know how can I get user geo location if all the condition for `mdm` are satisfied.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to be the [Apple Doc](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data_on_iOS.pdf) @ page #6 with topic **MDM cannot see and MDM can see.** is clearly written that we can get geo location from MDM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the device is supervised as well as managed by an MDM then you can send a command to enable lost mode and then request the device's location.

If the device is not supervised then you cannot enable lost mode or request the location.

Many MDM solutions install a companion app on the device and have this app request "always" location permissions. The MDM can then send a silent push to this app, requesting that it obtains and sends the current location. The user can, of course, decline location permission for the app.

Comment: How can I achieve this? How to set up for all this?

Comment: Actually I wanted to get the user geo location even my app is not active, one of the solutions is MDM. Is there any other good solution you have?